# С++ запрет ввода при достижении лимита

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. У меня в программе пользователь вводит имя или никнейм. Я заранее на это выделил массив из 15 символов и не более. Если использовать функцию getline(str,15), то она обрежет введенную строку до нужного размера, но пока пользователь печатает, он может набирать сколько угодно символов. Скажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы после 15-того символа в консоль переставали выводиться символы и пользователь понимал,что пора нажать ентер?

Answer (score 1):

На чистом C++ — никак. C++ написан в предположении, что пользователь может не иметь ни экрана, ни клавиатуры, поэтому поддерживает лишь потоковый ввод данных. (Да, я тоже считаю это глупостью со стороны архитекторов языка.)

Вам придётся использовать системно-специфические библиотеки. Для Windows это может быть просто WinAPI, для Linux-платформ вам пригодится библиотека `curses`.